# Importing all parts of a multipart email

Tags: import, email

Here is an email with two parts, a plaintext part and an HTML part:

```
email = "MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 5 Aug 2021 11:55:22 -0700
Message-ID: \
<abc123@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Test subj
From: Foo Bar <foo.bar@gmail.com>
To: Baz Yam <baz.yam@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; \
boundary=\"0000000000000eb0a805c8d4768f\"

--0000000000000eb0a805c8d4768f
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"

Part 1 of my email

--0000000000000eb0a805c8d4768f
Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"

<div dir=\"ltr\"><div>PART 2!!!!<br></div></div>

--0000000000000eb0a805c8d4768f--";
```

Importing the Body just imports the first part:

```
In[457]:= ImportString[email, {"EML", "Body"}]

Out[457]= "Part 1 of my email"
```

Importing the entire message, I can't find the message's second part anywhere:

```
In[458]:= 
ImportString[email, {"EML", "Rules"}] // 
 Cases[#, s_String /; StringContainsQ[s, "PART 2"]] &

Out[458]= {}
```

How can I import the message's second part, without having to manually parse it out?

Comment: Doesn't _multipart/alternative_ mean it's up to the agent to choose which part to take? It says [here in rfc1341](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) that multipart/alternative means semantically: _each of the parts is an "alternative" version of the same information_ . Typically used when you want plain and html versions of the same message. You should use _multipart/mixed_ instead - but Mathematica still fails to deal with it - in fact using the example on that page (make sure to strip all the leading whitespace) I get `"Body" -> None`

Comment: You are not finding Part 2 anywhere because `Cases` is only looking at the first level.  Use `Cases[#, s_String /; StringContainsQ[s, "PART 2"], Infinity] &` to search all levels.  Consider using `"Plaintext" /. ImportString[email, {"EML", "Rules"}]` instead.

Comment: @LouisB, thanks for pointing that out. Even adding `Infinity` to Cases, it still only finds the `text/html` portion **only** in the Plaintext field, where I would have to parse it out from the rest of the whole email. I was hoping MMA would offer something like `ImportString[email, {"EML", {"Multiparts",2} } ]` to parse it out for me.

Comment: @flinty, thanks for digging in to that RFC, I didn't know the difference between `multipart/alternative` and `multipart/mixed`. Interestingly, Wolfram Tech Support emails have `multipart/alternative` MIME types, yet their text/plain and text/html parts are very different. (I filed a support ticket with WRI about that.)